# How to replace expressions with variables?

Tags: replacement

```
(I Gr0 theta Sqrt[1 - theta^2]) / 
  (2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2))
```

Replace the denominator of the expression with `T1`，How can I achieve？I tried：
[image]

but failed.

Comment: why note just `Numerator[expr]/ T1` or `Simplify[expr, {Denominator[expr] == T1}]`?

Comment: When a replacement is failing, the way to understand why is to look at the `FullForm` of the expression. That's what you have to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr = (I Gr0 theta Sqrt[1 - theta^2]) / 
  (2 Gr0Mz (-1 + theta^2) (1 - 2 coff1 theta trMz wn + coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2));

Numerator[expr] / T1 (* or *)
Simplify[expr, {Denominator[expr] == T1}]
```

> ```
>  (I Gr0 theta Sqrt[1 - theta^2]) / T1
> ```